# 2 asp.net mvc sites conflicting with each other

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have deployed an asp.net mvc site a few days ago and everything is going fine.  I just deployed a second website (totally unrelated)

i just went to the first website and i am now getting an error below.  Can anyone help me determine what is going on.  I dont understand why they would know anything about each other.

**The controller name 'Home' is ambiguous between the following types:

Site.netmvc.Controllers.HomeController

SalemGolf.Controllers.HomeController

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The controller name 'Home' is ambiguous between the following types:

Site.netmvc.Controllers.HomeController

SalemGolf.Controllers.HomeController

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.   Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The controller name 'Home' is ambiguous between the following types:

Site.netmvc.Controllers.HomeController

SalemGolf.Controllers.HomeController]

   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(String controllerName, HashSet`1 namespaces) +417**
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(String controllerName) +286
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have the assembly of the other site in your Bin directory.

Comment: i have no idea how that got there :)

Comment: Not a human error. It's Visual Studio not doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you - didn't think of this and had burned ages of time.